# How can I do "cross-Excel version" testing? My OpenPyXL generated .xlsx file looks different on Mac vs LibreOffice vs Google Sheets

Tags: excel, testing, cross-platform, openpyxl

I recently built a report for a Django webapp that outputs an xlsx file that includes some charts using the OpenPyXL library.

I tested the export on LibreOffice and Google Sheets and everything looked right.  My client went to the site and opened the document in Excel for Mac version 16.  He says that the chart looks off (specifically the bar charts aren't stacking correctly).

Is there a way I can do "cross-Excel testing" in the same way I'd do cross-browser testing?  Does any service let me access all versions of Excel online?  What do you do when you have to test something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is really possible. The specification allows for quite a lot of leeway in the implementation and the different applications are not Excel clones but applications in their own right, with their own approach to spreadsheets. Specifically, LibreOffice and OpenOffice use the ODF format which differs in signficant details from OOXML.

In summary, you will need to make sure you have a setup similar to your customers. Microsoft has done a great job with Excel 2016 so that it now looks and behaves the same on the different platforms so that if something works with Excel 2016 for Windows, it should work with Excel 2016 for Mac.